# How to delete white stripes and unite the legends?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got this data:

|  | reg_month | no_ses_users | ses_users | no_ses_users_ptc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-01 | 29 | 101 | 22.31 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 | 48 | 188 | 20.34 |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 | 86 | 303 | 22.11 |
| 3 | 2021-04-01 | 111 | 381 | 22.56 |
| 4 | 2021-05-01 | 141 | 479 | 22.74 |
| 5 | 2021-06-01 | 177 | 564 | 23.89 |
| 6 | 2021-07-01 | 224 | 661 | 25.31 |
| 7 | 2021-08-01 | 257 | 746 | 25.62 |
| 8 | 2021-09-01 | 289 | 832 | 25.78 |
| 9 | 2021-10-01 | 319 | 934 | 25.46 |
| 10 | 2021-11-01 | 341 | 1019 | 25.07 |
| 11 | 2021-12-01 | 384 | 1111 | 25.69 |
| 12 | 2022-01-01 | 422 | 1203 | 25.97 |
| 13 | 2022-02-01 | 451 | 1292 | 25.87 |
| 14 | 2022-03-01 | 482 | 1377 | 25.93 |
| 15 | 2022-04-01 | 518 | 1468 | 26.08 |
| 16 | 2022-05-01 | 544 | 1553 | 25.94 |
| 17 | 2022-06-01 | 584 | 1633 | 26.34 |
| 18 | 2022-07-01 | 620 | 1722 | 26.47 |
| 19 | 2022-08-01 | 651 | 1813 | 26.42 |
| 20 | 2022-09-01 | 662 | 1847 | 26.39 |

I make graph with second axis with plt.bar (y axis), plt.plot (second y axis):

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns

    sns.set_style('darkgrid')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
    
    ax1 = plt.bar(
        x=df2_3['reg_month'],
        height=df2_3['ses_users'],
        label='Users with sessions',
        edgecolor = 'black',
        linewidth = 0,
        width=20,
        color = '#3049BF'
    )
    
    ax2 = plt.bar(
        x=df2_3['reg_month'],
        height=df2_3['no_ses_users'],
        bottom=df2_3['ses_users'],
        label='Users without sessions',
        edgecolor = 'black',
        linewidth = 0,
        width=20,
        color = '#BF9530'
    )
    
    secax = ax.twinx()
    secax.set_ylim(min(df2_3['no_ses_users_ptc'])*0.5, max(df2_3['no_ses_users_ptc'])*1.1)

    ax3 = plt.plot(
        df2_3['reg_month'],
        df2_3['no_ses_users_ptc'],
        color = '#E97800',
        label='Users without sessions, ptc'
    )
    
    ax.legend()
    secax.legend()
    
    plt.show()
```

How can I delete white stipes and unite the legend at one?

Output:
[image: plt.show]

Comment: The White Stripes are Legend.

Comment: Haha. You should text this as the answer. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the legends, you need to get the individual handles & labels for ax and secax, combine them and plot the same. The white lines you are seeing are the grid lines. You can turn them off using axes.grid(False). Add these lines just before plt.show() (and comment out your exsting legend lines) like below...

```
ax.grid(False)    ## Turn off grid lines for ax
secax.grid(False) ## Turn off grid lines for secax

h1, l1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()    ## Get the legend handles and labels for ax
h2, l2 = secax.get_legend_handles_labels() ## Get the legend handles and labels for secax

handles = h1 + h2  ## Combine handles
labels = l1 + l2   ## Combine labels
ax.legend(handles, labels)  ## Plot the combined legend

#ax.legend()    ## Need to comment out
#secax.legend() ## Need to comment out

plt.show()
```

[image]